# Text Selection Behavior in Chrome and Firefox for Elements with Padding

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, textselection

When a user selects text div, most browsers change the background color of the text. You can customize that background color with CSS like so:

```
.test::-moz-selection  {
    background: red;
}
.test::selection {
    background: red;
}
```

However, I am noticing some strange behavior in Chrome when you modify the selection background.

Sometimes the entire element is selected including the padding, sometimes just the text portion is selected, and sometimes a portion of the padding is selected.  Below is a link to a jsfiddle, try selecting the Xs. How can I get consistent behavior out of Chrome? (Either all padding or no padding should be selected).

http://jsfiddle.net/L8kzLy6h/3/

If you try it in Firefox, the selection is much more consistent (padding is not selected).

Comment: I ahd a look and couldn't get my head around it, one thing you could do is change the font color,size, textshadow etc... instead of the background to give a customized selected text. Don't know if that's any good in your case though

Comment: Looks like things have improved. Chrome now works the same as Firefox, no padding is selected. Also tried IE and it's also the same. Hooray for progress.